# Laravel uploading file with chunk and getting FileException error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

i'm trying to use [pionl/laravel-chunk-upload](https://github.com/pionl/laravel-chunk-upload) and [Resumable.js](http://www.resumablejs.com/) to upload large file into server

i implemented view, controller and route and now when i try to upload file i get this error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException: The
>   file "XXXXXXXX" was not uploaded due to an unknown error. in file
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\XXX\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\File\UploadedFile.php
>   on line 213

and i can't fix this error:

**view**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="resumable-error">
        Your browser, unfortunately, is not supported by Resumable.js. The library requires support for <a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/">the HTML5 File API</a> along with <a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#normalization-of-params">file slicing</a>.
    </div>
    <div class="resumable-drop">
        Drop video files here to upload or <a class="resumable-browse"><u>select from your computer</u></a>
    </div>
    <div class="resumable-progress">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100%"><div class="progress-container"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div></td>
                <td class="progress-text" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
                <td class="progress-pause" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <a href="#" onclick="r.upload(); return(false);" class="progress-resume-link"><img src="/assets/global_assets/images/icons/resume.png" title="Resume upload" /></a>
                    <a href="#" onclick="r.pause(); return(false);" class="progress-pause-link"><img src="/assets/global_assets/images/icons/pause.png" title="Pause upload" /></a>
                    <a href="#" onclick="r.cancel(); return(false);" class="progress-cancel-link"><img src="/assets/global_assets/images/icons/cancel.png" title="Cancel upload" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar mb-2 resumable-list p-0 pl-3 m-0" data-nav-type="accordion"></ul>
</div>


<script>
    var r = new Resumable({
        target: '/panel/uploadRadioChannelFile',
        chunkSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024,
        testChunks: false,
        throttleProgressCallbacks: 1,
        headers:{
            'X-CSRF-Token' :"{{ csrf_token() }}"
        },
        query:{
            _token : "{{ csrf_token() }}"
        }
    });
    // Resumable.js isn't supported, fall back on a different method
    if (!r.support) {
        $('.resumable-error').show();
    } else {
        // Show a place for dropping/selecting files
        $('.resumable-drop').show();
        r.assignDrop($('.resumable-drop')[0]);
        r.assignBrowse($('.resumable-browse')[0]);

        // Handle file add event
        r.on('fileAdded', function (file) {
            // Show progress pabr
            $('.resumable-progress, .resumable-list').show();
            // Show pause, hide resume
            $('.resumable-progress .progress-resume-link').hide();
            $('.resumable-progress .progress-pause-link').show();
            // Add the file to the list
            $('.resumable-list').append('<li class="nav-item resumable-file-' + file.uniqueIdentifier + '">Uploading <span class="resumable-file-name"></span> <span class="resumable-file-progress"></span>');
            $('.resumable-file-' + file.uniqueIdentifier + ' .resumable-file-name').html(file.fileName);
            // Actually start the upload
            r.upload();
        });
        r.on('pause', function () {
            // Show resume, hide pause
            $('.resumable-progress .progress-resume-link').show();
            $('.resumable-progress .progress-pause-link').hide();
        });
        r.on('complete', function () {
            // Hide pause/resume when the upload has completed
            $('.resumable-progress .progress-resume-link, .resumable-progress .progress-pause-link').hide();
        });
        r.on('fileSuccess', function (file, message) {
            // Reflect that the file upload has completed
            $('.resumable-file-' + file.uniqueIdentifier + ' .resumable-file-progress').html('(completed)');
        });
        r.on('fileError', function (file, message) {
            // Reflect that the file upload has resulted in error
            $('.resumable-file-' + file.uniqueIdentifier + ' .resumable-file-progress').html('(file could not be uploaded: ' + message + ')');
        });
        r.on('fileProgress', function (file) {
            // Handle progress for both the file and the overall upload
            $('.resumable-file-' + file.uniqueIdentifier + ' .resumable-file-progress').html(Math.floor(file.progress() * 100) + '%');
            $('.progress-bar').css({width: Math.floor(r.progress() * 100) + '%'});
        });
        r.on('cancel', function () {
            $('.resumable-file-progress').html('canceled');
        });
        r.on('uploadStart', function () {
            // Show pause, hide resume
            $('.resumable-progress .progress-resume-link').hide();
            $('.resumable-progress .progress-pause-link').show();
        });
    }
</script>
```

**route**:

```
Route::post('uploadRadioChannelFile', 'UploadController@upload');
```

and **`controller`**:

```
class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $receiver = new FileReceiver("file", $request, HandlerFactory::classFromRequest($request));

            if ($receiver->isUploaded() === false) {
                return response()->json([
                    "done" => '',
                    'status' => false
                ]);
            }

            $save = $receiver->receive();

            if ($save->isFinished()) {
                return $this->saveFile($save->getFile());
            }

            $handler = $save->handler();

            return response()->json([
                "done" => $handler->getPercentageDone(),
                'status' => true
            ]);
        } catch (UploadFailedException $e) {
        }
    }

    protected function saveFile(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $fileName = $this->createFilename($file);
        //$mime = str_replace('/', '-', $file->getMimeType());
        $dateFolder = Carbon::now()->year;

        $public_html = config('app.public_path');

        $filePath = "upload/{$dateFolder}/";

        $file->move($public_html.$filePath, $fileName);

        return response()->json([
            'path' => $filePath,
            'name' => $fileName,
            'ffff' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
        ]);
    }

    protected function createFilename(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        //$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //$filename = str_replace("." . $extension, "", $file->getClientOriginalName()); // Filename without extension
        //$filename .= "_" . md5(time()) . "." . $extension;

        return time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    }
}
```